# Integration by parts, Weinberg Cosmology p.526

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, variational-calculus

How do I perform this integration by parts done explicitly?

$$0 = \delta I_m = \int d^4 \sqrt{-g} T^{\mu \nu} \left[- \frac{\partial \epsilon^\rho}{\partial x^\mu} g_{\nu \rho} - \frac{\partial \epsilon^\rho}{\partial x^\nu} g_{\mu \rho} - \frac{\partial g_{\mu \nu }}{\partial x^\rho} \epsilon^\rho \right] .$$

By integrating by parts and setting the coefficient $\epsilon$ to zero, we will get the the conservation condition.

$$D_\mu T^{\mu \nu}=0.$$

Comment: Reference: Weinberg, _Gravitation & Cosmology,_ 1972; p. 363.

Answer (score 1):

The expression 
$$
\epsilon^\rho \partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu} + g_{\mu\lambda}\partial_\nu \epsilon^\lambda +g_{\lambda\nu}\partial_\mu \epsilon^\lambda
$$
is the Lie derivative ${\mathcal L}_\epsilon g$ of $g_{\mu\nu}$ with respect to the vector field $\epsilon$. It is a tensor quantity and  therefore can also be expressed as 
$$
({\mathcal L}_\epsilon g)_{\mu\nu}= \nabla_\mu \epsilon_\nu+ \nabla_\nu \epsilon_\mu.
$$
This is  tedious to verify by expanding out  using Christoffel sysmbols, but it has to be true because the two expressions are tensors and agree in local normal coordinates where $\partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu}=0$.  Now you can use the derivation property of the covariant derivatives together with
$$
\nabla_\mu V^\mu = \frac 1{\sqrt{-g}} \partial_\mu \sqrt{-g} V^\mu
$$
where 
$$
V^\mu\equiv T^{\mu\nu}\epsilon_\nu
$$
to straightforwardly integrate by parts  and see  that your expression is equal to 
$$
2\int \sqrt{-g} \epsilon^\nu \nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu} d^4x. 
$$
Since this is true for arbitrary $\epsilon^\nu$ we have $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$. I won't exhibit  the "straightforward" manipulations because they really are easy.